# Проблема с выравниванием строк python библиотеки 'prettytable'

Tags: python, tkinter

При выводе текста в конслоль ide получаю сбой при выравнивании.
Участок кода:

```
pointparameters = PrettyTable()
pointparameters.field_names = ['Key', 'Value', 'Unit of measure']
pointparameters.add_row(["Device name:", str(devicename_value[1]), 'str' ])
pointparameters.add_row(["Platform:", str(deviceplatform_value[1]), 'type'])
pointparameters.add_row(["Mac address:", str(apMac_value[1]), 'str'])
pointparameters.add_row(["Signal:", signal_value[1], 'dBm'])
pointparameters.add_row(["CCQ:", str(ccq_split_percent_value).replace('.',','), '%'])
pointparameters.add_row(["Frequency:", freq_value[1], 'mHz'])
pointparameters.add_row(["Distance:", str(distance_split_percent_value).replace('.',','), 'm'])
pointparameters.add_row(["Wlan Tx Rate:", str(wlanTxRate_value[1]).replace('.',','), 'Mbps'])
pointparameters.add_row(["Wlan Rx Rate:", str(wlanRxRate_value[1]).replace('.',','), 'Mbps'])
pointparameters.add_row(["Lan speed:", str(lanSpeed_value[1]), 'Mbps'])
pointparameters.add_row(["Uptime:", str(uptime_split_percent_value).replace('.',','), 'hs'])
pointparameters.add_row(["latitude:", str(latitude_value).replace('.',','), 'float'])
pointparameters.add_row(["Longitud:", str(longitude_value).replace('.',','), 'float'])

pointparameters.align = 'l'
print(pointparameters)
```

Вывод в консоль представлен на изображении.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выводе в поле Text tkinter ситуация немного лучше но все равно слетает выравнивание.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: выравнивие форматом впм не поможет ? https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html

Comment: Можно попробовать но нюанс в том что в консоли часть строк вообще не выводится.Подозреваю проблема с шрифтами, гугление показало что я не единственный кто столкнулся с такой проблемой но четкого ответа не смог найти. Чаще всего пишут что проблема в том что изначально данный не в моноширном формате. соответственно у них нет ыиксированной динны символа, похоже на правду но вопрос как это исправить?

Comment: вывод обязательно в консоле делать ? в ткинтере текст выводить как текстовое поле а разделять  lable  или нарисовать на canvas прямые длинные линии

Comment: Основная задача все таки в tkinter выводить, консль просто для теста, если вней все норм будет - значит и в tkinter все ровно выведется.

Comment: Частично решил проблему указав типы данных для каждой строки, хз в чем проблема.Единственное осталось смещение для строки с мак адресом. pointparameters.add_row(["Wlan Tx Rate:", float(wlanTxRate_value[1]), 'Mbps'])
pointparameters.add_row(["Wlan Rx Rate:", float(wlanRxRate_value[1]),'Mbps'])